# Spring Dependency Injection of nested beans

Tags: java, spring

I'm fighting with Spring Dependency Injection and nested beans: There are two beans and one of them is nested in the other. When inspecting the outer bean, I can see, that the inner bean isn't injected.

The main class:

```
public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx
      = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext("org.acme");

    MyService myService = ctx.getBean(MyService.class);
    // do something with myService
  }
}
```

The outer bean:

```
@Component
public class MyService {

  @Inject // javax.inject.Inject
  private MyDao dao;

  public MyService() {
    System.out.println(dao);
  }
}
```

The inner bean:

```
@Component
public class MyDao {

  public MyDao() {
    System.out.println("dao is alive");
  }
}
```

There is no error when starting the application, but I see `null` getting printed out by the constructor of `MyService` and `dao is alive`. I had the same issue when trying with a `@Configuration` class. It seems like the outer beans depedencies won't be injected.

Thx!

Answer (score 3):

As fields and methods parameters are injected after the constructor is called, you cannot use injected member variables in the constructor.

[reference](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/DependencyInjection/article.html#dependencyinjection_order)

Answer (score 1):

I made it work with **constructor injection**.

```
@Component
public class MyService {

  private MyDao dao;

  @Inject // javax.inject.Inject
  public MyService(MyDao dao) {
    System.out.println(dao);
  }
}
```